# Call another webmethod in select using jQuery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

In my app, I am using jQuery autocomplete to fill a textbox and a hidden field with the id. It is working fine.

Now i want to pull some more data based on the id selected. I am new to jQuery and could not find any other threads based on this. Here is the code I use for select an item from the list

```
                    select: function (event, ui) 
                {
                    this.value = ui.item.value;
                    $("#" + name).val(ui.item.label);
                    $("#" + idfld).val(ui.item.value);
                    return false;
                }
```

inside this function I want to call another web method which will return data corresponding to the id. I want to fill other textboxes based on this data.

Comment: look at [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax) :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it by getting more values into the same field. This is the code

```
.autocomplete(
            {
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        url: "../svc/SearchService.svc/GetMatchingVehiclesInfo",
                        data: "VehicleSearchName=" + $("#" + name).val(),
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.GetMatchingVehiclesInfoResult, function (value, key) {
                                return {
                                    label: value.Name, //vehicle name
                                    //below i combined multiple values into same field
                                    value: value.ID + '#' + value.BodyType + '#' + value.FuelType + '#' + value.Seats
                                };
                            }));
                        },
                        error: function (result) {
                            alert("Error");
                        }
                    });
                },
                search: function () {
                    // custom minLength
                    var term = extractLast(this.value);
                    if (term.length < 1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    this.value = ui.item.value;
                    $("#" + name).val(ui.item.label);
                    //here i extracted the value using split       
                    $("#<%=hdnVehicle.ClientID%>").val(ui.item.value.split('#')[0]);
                    $("#<%=ddlFueltype.ClientID%>").value = ui.item.value.split('#')[2];
                    return false;
                }
```

But even if I get the value, `dropdownlist(ddlFueltype)` value is not changing. I'm trying to figure it out.